# social auth, google+, no email in reply

Tags: django, authentication, python-social-auth

Using `python-social-auth` in my Django app.

I am trying to get Google+ authentication to work, but Google+ doesn't give me an email.

What I get from Google is this:

```
dict: {'username': '',
       'fullname': u'Alex Laban',
       'last_name': u'Laban',
       'email': '',
       'first_name': u'Alex'}`
```

My authorisation is built around email, therefore, without email this Google+ service is useless.

How do I get Google to return email?

---

UPD: Configuration:

View:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        plus_scope = ' '.join(GooglePlusAuth.DEFAULT_SCOPE)
        plus_id = getattr(settings, 'SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_KEY', None)

        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form, 'plus_scope' : plus_scope, 'plus_id' : plus_id})
```

Default scope is `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'`

Template:

```
  <div>
    <form id="google-plus" method="post" action="{% url "social:complete" backend="google-plus" %}">{% csrf_token %}
      <input id="at" type="hidden" name="access_token" value="" />
      <input id="code" type="hidden" name="code" value="" />

      <div id="signinButton">
        <span class="g-signin" data-scope="{{ plus_scope }}"
                               data-clientid="{{ plus_id }}"
                               data-redirecturi="postmessage"
                               data-accesstype="offline"
                               data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                               data-callback="signInCallback">
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=start" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var signInCallback = function (result) {
          if (result['error']) {
            console.log(result);
          } else {
            $('#code').attr('value', result['code']);
            $('#at').attr('value', result['access_token']);
            $('#google-plus').submit();
          }
      };
    </script>
  </div>
```

Settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_ADMIN_USER_SEARCH_FIELDS = ['email', 'name']
SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY = 'social.strategies.django_strategy.DjangoStrategy'
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'social.apps.django_app.default.models.DjangoStorage'

USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
#    'social.pipeline.debug.debug'
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_KEY = 'top-secret.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_SECRET = 'try-guess'
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'social.apps.django_app.default',
)

 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
            'social.backends.google.GooglePlusAuth',
            'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',

            'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 )
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
'social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
)
```

Google Developers Console

Google+ API is enabled

**Client ID for web application** is generated with:

- Redirect URIS: `http://localhost:8000/complete/google-plus/`
- Javascript Origins `http://localhost:8000`

Public API access. I'm not sure if it's needed, but just in case have two keys:

- **Key for server applications** with IPs 127.0.0.1
- **Key for browser applications** with Referers `http://localhost:8000/`

But I guess it isn't used anywhere...

Ideas? Can it be on google site that I mis-configured something in developer console?

Comment: Any configuration? To be clear you are using ``/login/google-plus/``, right? What happens if you define this setting ``SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_USE_DEPRECATED_API = True``? Do you have Google+ API enabled in your project (check in google console)?

Comment: @omab, thank you! please, see the update of the original post

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I figured that out.

The default scope must be extended with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`

This will force google to return email as well.

Thank you.